# Parse IDs from input string to long number using Span<T> in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, memory

I'm trying to parse different IDs(long) from a single string which contains different number, and I need to minimize memory allocation for the performance.

Below is the code extracting IDs using Split, but I found that I could use AsSpan and Splice to do the same without allocating memory. But unfortunately I'm not so familiar with this Span concept even after looking up on the web. Can anyone please chime in how I can achieve this?

As you can see below, input string has 3 different IDs but I only need 2 of them and parse into long type.

```
        string[] machineIdPart;
        string[] employeeIdPart;
        long machineId;            
        long employeeId;

        //Input String
        var description = "machineId: 276744, engineId: 59440, employeeId: 4619825";

        Console.Out.Write(description);
        Console.Out.WriteLine();
        var infoList = description.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var info in infoList)
        {
            if (info.TrimStart().StartsWith("machineId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                machineIdPart = info.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (machineIdPart.Count() > 1)
                {
                    long.TryParse(machineIdPart[1].Trim(), out machineId);
                }                                     
            }

            if (info.TrimStart().StartsWith("employeeId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                employeeIdPart = info.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (employeeIdPart.Count() > 1)
                {
                    long.TryParse(employeeIdPart[1].Trim(), out employeeId);
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to modify this code to minimize memory allocation as this method will be run extremely frequently.

Comment: are you seeing any performance issues now?

Comment: You'll find that parsing `long`s from `string`s is none too fast either. Consider doing this the old-fashioned way by jumping through the string hunting for `,`, and parsing yourself with `x = x * 10 + c - '0'`, avoiding all string manipulation in one swell foop. This can be done from `Span` as well if that's still a perf issue, but that's on another level (it would mean extracting `description` in a more efficient way as well). However, per Matt -- establish this is an actual bottleneck first, even if you know it will run "extremely frequently". Optimizing the wrong thing is a waste of time.

Comment: @Matt.G I would say yes. Above code will be inserted in part of huge processing code. After making above change, it added a performance overhead compare without. It was not significant, but still would like to improve more to minimize the impact.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, please see my above comment. Can you also please be able to elaborate more on that 'old-fashioned' way using Span if you don't mind??

Comment: Write a simple parser by keeping track of where you are (index) instead of actually creating new strings. For a string this simple, repeated calls to `.IndexOf` would do, although you could also write a little state machine (`switch (description[i]) { case ':': state = State.ParsingNumber; ++i; break; }`). The main idea is to leave the string for what it is and not create new ones. Parsing this string without allocating anything can be done in many ways; you don't even need to dive into `Span` for this. (No, I can't be bothered to actually write the parser now, sorry. :-P)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution works with .NET Core 2.2. It utilizes allocation-free extension method on `ReadOnlySpan<char>` (`SplitNext`).

```
public class Program {
    public void MyAnswer() {
        long machineId = 0;
        long employeeId = 0;

        var description = "machineId: 276744, engineId: 59440, employeeId: 4619825";

        var span = description.AsSpan();
        while (span.Length > 0) {
            var entry = span.SplitNext(',');

            var key = entry.SplitNext(':').TrimStart(' ');
            var value = entry.TrimStart(' ');

            if (key.Equals("machineId", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
                long.TryParse(value, out machineId);
            }
            if (key.Equals("employeeId", StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
                long.TryParse(value, out employeeId);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Extensions {
    public static ReadOnlySpan<char> SplitNext(this ref ReadOnlySpan<char> span, char seperator) {
        int pos = span.IndexOf(seperator);
        if (pos > -1) {
            var part = span.Slice(0, pos);
            span = span.Slice(pos + 1);
            return part;
        } else {
            var part = span;
            span = span.Slice(span.Length);
            return part;
        }
    }
}
```

I compared your original code, the existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55010541/542008) and my answer via BenchmarkDotnet. It shows that this solution is indeed allocation-free and performs faster than the original version:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.4, OS=Windows 10.0.17763.316 (1809/October2018Update/Redstone5)
Intel Core i5-2500K CPU 3.30GHz (Sandy Bridge), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 4 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.2.104
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.2.2 (CoreCLR 4.6.27317.07, CoreFX 4.6.27318.02), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.2.2 (CoreCLR 4.6.27317.07, CoreFX 4.6.27318.02), 64bit RyuJIT

|   Method |       Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Gen 0/1k Op | Gen 1/1k Op | Gen 2/1k Op | Allocated Memory/Op |
|--------- |-----------:|----------:|----------:|------------:|------------:|------------:|--------------------:|
| Original | 1,164.1 ns | 11.606 ns | 10.289 ns |      0.2937 |           - |           - |               928 B |
|   Answer |   460.5 ns |  4.527 ns |  4.234 ns |           - |           - |           - |                   - |
| MyAnswer |   445.7 ns |  2.578 ns |  2.412 ns |           - |           - |           - |                   - |
```

Apart from the string-handling optimizations, the actual parsing function can also be optimized. This would be a faster long-parser:

```
    public static long LongParseFast(ReadOnlySpan<char> value) {
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
            result = 10 * result + (value[i] - 48);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If used in my sample, it doubles performance to `216.0 ns` in my benchmarks. Of course this function cannot deal with things like negative numbers, commas, points and other locale stuff. But if you're ok with that, this is probably as fast as you can get.

Comment: Thanks! this indeed is the fastest on my bench mark test. Btw, do you mind if you could tell how you were able to generate Allocated Memory column using Benchmarkdotnet ? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure. Just ad `[MemoryDiagnoser]` attribute to the class you want to benchmark. Here is my full benchmark code: https://gist.github.com/discostu105/69103b549a392182fbfa2b09d11cee2f

Answer (score 1):

The solution will become little more complicated than current, but there will be no more string allocations. Works for .NET Core 2.2

```
long machineId = 0;
long employeeId = 0;

var description = "machineId: 276744, engineId: 59440, employeeId: 4619825";

ReadOnlySpan<char> descriptionSpan = description.AsSpan();

var nameValueBlockStartIndex = 0;
while(nameValueBlockStartIndex < description.Length)
{
    var blockEndIndex = description.IndexOf(',', nameValueBlockStartIndex);
    if (blockEndIndex == -1)
    {
        blockEndIndex = description.Length;
    }

    var namePartEndIndex = description.IndexOf(':', nameValueBlockStartIndex);
    var namePartLength = namePartEndIndex - nameValueBlockStartIndex;
    var namePart = descriptionSpan.Slice(nameValueBlockStartIndex, namePartLength);

    var valuePartStartIndex = namePartEndIndex + 1;
    var valuePartLength = blockEndIndex - valuePartStartIndex + 1;
    var valuePart = descriptionSpan.Slice(valuePartStartIndex, valuePartLength - 1);

    while(namePart[0] == ' ')
    {
        namePart = namePart.Slice(1);
    }

    if (namePart.Equals("machineId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Int64.TryParse(valuePart, out machineId);
    }
    else if (namePart.Equals("employeeId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Int64.TryParse(valuePart, out employeeId);
    }

    nameValueBlockStartIndex = blockEndIndex + 1;
}
```